# Right align just one chapter title with `fncychap` package loaded

Tags: sectioning, report, fncychap

I want to right align just one unnumbered chapter in my `report` class document. Normally it can be accomplished in a very simple manner, `\chapter*{\raggedleft <chapter title>}`. But I suspect it must have to do with the fact that I use `fncychap` package that doing the same as above does not change anything. How do I go about this?

Comment: Try `\chapter[title]{\raggedleft title}`.  If it is only one line, `\hfill` will do instead of `\raggedleft`..

Comment: Thanks! `\hfill` works although I would still expect to use the alignment command like `\ragged...` and `\centering` because at some other places I need the title to be centered for which `\centering` is the most suitable I think.